# Can't find object method in interactive session

Tags: python, tqdm

I am trying to reuse the same `tqdm` progress bar for multiple purposes. The tqdm object has a `reset()` method that clears the bar, so that's what I'm trying to use. 
I made a simple example to try it out:

```py
import time
from tqdm import tqdm

s = tqdm(range(50))
for _ in s:
    time.sleep(.01)

s.reset()

for _ in s:
    time.sleep(.05)
```

When I run that in my interactive ipython console, I get the error:

```py
AttributeError: 'tqdm' object has no attribute 'reset'
```

However, when I put this code in a script and run it from the terminal (i.e. `python test.py`), this works just fine.
I'm not sure if this problem is specific to the `tqdm` package or if it's a more general issue linked to python's way of importing modules/objects.

Any hint would be very helpful!

EDIT:

- Python 3.7.3
- IPython 7.6.1
- tqdm==4.40.2

SOLVED:

I had to manually remove all tqdm files inside my virtualenv directory (`lib/python3.7/site-packages`, `bin/`) and then reinstall tqdm

Comment: I tried to install the same versions of your packages (`tqdm` and `ipython`), same error for me.

Comment: Then could you provide more information about your installation of Python / environment (virtualenv, conda, ...)?

Comment: I'm using a virtualenv on a MacOS Mojave.
I just tried on a Ubuntu machine with Python 3.7.4, and it worked. So I guess the problem probably comes either from the python version or the OS

Comment: Can you check the `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH` environment variables when the error occurs?

Comment: Hmm, so my PYTHONPATH was empty, and I tried setting my PATH to simply my virtualenv bin directory but it was still not working. Then, I deleted all tqdm related files in my virtualenv, and to reinstall the package with pip, and this time it worked.